# ActiveRecord not reading method parameters correctly

Tags: ruby, activerecord, sinatra

I'm experiencing some very peculiar results from my Sinatra project.

Everything's been working fine, then this morning I started getting errors in my ActiveRecord calls.

My first call is to get a random row from my Countries table

This fails:

`@randomCountry = Country.where( "name != ?", @countryName ).first( :order => "RANDOM()" )`

with the following error:

`can't convert Hash into Integer`

If I leave out the :order, I don't get an error, so this works:

`@randomCountry = Country.where( "name != ?", @countryName ).first()`

But obviously isn't ideal as it's not random any more!

Then a little bit further down I get a full countries list like this:

`@countriesList = Country.find(:all, :order => "name")`

this errors with the following:

`Couldn't find all Countries with 'code': (all, {:order=>"name"}) (found 0 results, but was looking for 2)`

If I omit the order by name:

`@countriesList = Country.find(:all)`

I get this error:

`Couldn't find Country with 'code'=all`

My country has a primary key of code, but I've previously been able to make this call without any problems at all.

Any help trying to debug this is much appreciated, I can post more detail if it's required.

Comment: Looking here: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FinderMethods.html#method-i-find it doesn't look like there's any support for :all on the find method.  What version of ActiveRecord are you on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using any recent version of AR, try:

```
Country.where("name != ?", @countryName).order('RANDOM()').first
# If you're using AR 4 you can do:
# Country.where.not(name: @countryName).order('RANDOM()').first
```

and

```
Country.order('name').all
```

Comment: Thanks @kardeiz, that's fixed my problem. Any idea why this might have stopped working? I'm not explicitly setting an AR version in my Gemfile, might the old syntax have become unsupported after a rogue bundle?

Comment: Additionally what is the most up to date stable version of AR? So I can set it explicitly.

Comment: @jolyonruss, it looks like support for `AR#find(:all)` and similar were dropped in 3.2. I believe the latest stable version of Rails (and ActiveRecord) is 4.1.4.

Comment: thanks - I've locked with the following `gem "activerecord", "4.0.2"`